# how to make https request from stack in aws cloud formation

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-cloudformation-custom-resource

example.
i am using **cloud-formation** for this

1. have to create **A** and **B** instance to handle traffic.
2. when A is created using stack resource have to check by using http request for A.
3. if A is given 200 ok .. then I will proceed with creation of B instance .
4. if A is not running and up then have to rollback this stack.

need help to how to make **https request** with the created resource within same stack and on the basis of response move further or rollback.

Comment: I see [tag:aws-cloudformation-custom-resource] in question tags. Custom resources are a way to solve this. So, what's stopping you?

Comment: Not 100% clear on what you're trying to do, but by "within same stack" I take it some resource created in that stack should make an http request to some other resource created in that same stack, and then stack creation either succeeds or fails based on the response? That can definitely be done through a custom resource, in fact I do similar stuff (no http but a custom resource that acts on resources created in the same stack), but there's a lot of code/concepts involved so too much for a single answer, unless you want to focus your question more on a specific bit of it.

Comment: actually i am trying with the CreationPolicy attribute with cfn-signal ..but looking for the any alternate option to do this .....i will update here if I am done or anything help here